# Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet — Maybe You Forgot to Add Reanimated’s babel Plugin?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have tried all I can think of to fix this error. I have tried uninstalling reanimated-bottom-sheet and react-native-reanimated and reinstalling them. Clearing cache. I do not have a babel.config.js file that I am aware of to edit. I know the error comes from this exact import below.

```
import BottomSheet from 'reanimated-bottom-sheet';
```

I have also linked a repository in order to reproduce my exact issue [here](https://github.com/priedejm/stackoverflow). I added my node_modules just in case, I am not sure if it would help someone see what I was doing wrong or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `babel.config.js` in root directory of the project (near package.json) with following context (or just grab it from https://github.com/software-mansion-labs/reanimated-2-playground):

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

Check reanimated docs https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Comment: try clear expo cache using ```expo start -c```

Comment: also probably you are missing react-native-reanimated inside package.json

Comment: check docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/

Comment: If someone is still having issues, you may have a `.babelrc` file which you should be updating instead of `babel.config.*`

Answer (score 0):

I added 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' to babel.config.js - but I had also .babelrc... stay with only one of them...

Answer (score 0):

`__reanimatedWorkletInit` function and `__worklet` property have been removed in `react-native-reanimated@2.7.0`.

Check reanimated releases https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/releases.

In my case i just downgraded to `react-native-reanimated@2.6.0` and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If using expo, use

```
expo install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler
```

instead of

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler
```

and then exit server then run `expo r -c`
This worked for me.